# Is there a more general measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-measure

I just have a soft question about measure theory. It's not for a class or anything; just asking because I'm curious and want to learn more. Is there a more general concept of measure on $\mathbb{R}$ than the Lebesgue measure?

I know that if $X$ is a non-empty set and $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, then $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ is a measurable space and if $\mu^{*}:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,+\infty]$ is an outer measure, then $\mu=\mu^{*}|_{\mathfrak{M}}$ is a measure. Hence, $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{L},m)$ is a measure space where $\mathfrak{L}$ is the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. So, is there any measure $\mu$ so that $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is more of an abstract measure space?

For instance, I have heard of the Guage integral and that it is more general in the sense that it can integrate a larger class of functions than the Lebesgue integral can. Does something like that actually rely on a measure?

Thanks for any remarks!

Comment: What do you mean by "more general"?  What do you mean by "more abstract"?  There are loads of $\sigma$-algebras that you can put on $\mathbb{R}$, and, generally speaking, multiple measures that can be defined on any given $\sigma$-algebra. What, exactly, are you after?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I guess I'm actually more after integration. Is there an integral more general than the Lebesgue integral which relies on a measure different from the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @WarTurtle, again, what do you mean by "more general integral"? The integral which can integrate a larger class of functions (which would mean you want measurable sets other than Lebesgue measurable)?

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин That's basically what I'm asking. Like for instance, I have heard of the Guage integral and that it is more general in the sense that it can integrate a larger class of functions than the Lebesgue integral can. Does something like that actually rely on a measure?

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that the Lebesgue measure is the maximal measure which behaves correctly under linear transformations (multiplies by the determinant). I'm really, really unsure, though. But I'm sure that you need to edit your question :)